# Avoid rewriting of file on Solaris OS

Tags: c, linux, solaris

I have a problem with certain C library functions (the souce code of which I have no access to, by the way) that are logging to files. Some versions of these libraries were compiled with the functions appending to the log files. But previous ones do not append at all.

Is there some way (like with chattr in Linux) to "force" the operation to go in append mode? I'm not allowed to do any specific operations on the files, like copying them before restarting the agents using these libraries ... so my only option is forcing these functions to append to the files regardless of how they've been programmed to open them.

Thanks.

Comment: Hm... this is going to be somewhat uggly. You could try to interpose the `open()` function to smuggle an `O_APPEND` in as a dirty hack.

Comment: There could be clear security violations of modifying, read, hack, the libraries to enable this sort of file opening with append mode hacked in place. Find the library that is responsible, do a systrace on whereabouts within the libraries is it calling another, until you get the root library that handles the calls, is it worth it?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use an [interposing dynamic library](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626005255/http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/lib_interposers.html) that would overload either the `libc` `fopen` or the `open` functions and would change on the fly their mode argument when the requested file is one of the target ones. [Here](http://technopark02.blogspot.fr/2005/05/solaris-hijacking-function-call.html) is an example precisely interposing the `fopen` call that you can easily adapt to your needs.

Alternatively, you can use `dtrace` in the so called destructive mode to intercept the same open calls and either patch on the fly the parameters or backup the file before it is overwritten.

[Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/funhouse/entry/dtrace_working_aroung) is an example of a similar hack.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to set the `O_APPEND` flag with dtrace in destructive mode.  The `O_APPEND` bit is set in `arg1` (or `args[1]`) in the Solaris 10 `open[64]` probe (`arg2` or `args[2]` in Solaris 11, which only has the `openat[64]` probe).  I don't think it's possible to modify the actual values passed to the function that triggered the dtrace probe.  The only option I can think of would be to modify the process file descriptor table in the return probe after the file is opened, but that assumes that merely setting the `O_APPEND` flag in the table is sufficient.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Saving the existing file might indeed be the best approach if going the `dtrace` way.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible workaround I can imagine is to rename the log file as soon as it has been created. As the program has an open file descriptor to it, it can continue to write there, but the next open will create a different file.

You could for example use a daemon process that scans the directory where the log files reside and appropriately rename them as soon as it find one.

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris 11 and later, the equivalent of the `chattr` command you're looking for is `chmod S+vappendonly file` but it must be done as root and will cause attempts to overwrite existing data or to open the file in the wrong mode to get errors instead of just translating the operation to silently appending, so may not work with some applications (for instance, *vi* doesn't work on such a file).

Comment: Unfortunately, dealing with Solaris 8 in my case, but thanks. Didn't know about chmod S+vappendonly.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the answers involve kludges and hacks of some sort, here's mine:

- Create the log "file" as a named pipe, using `mkfifo`.
- Run a process
  that reads from the named pipe and does nothing but append what it
  reads to the real log file.
- Test the application to make sure this works.

This, off the top of my head, might very well do as the "process":

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ 1 ]; do
    cat /this/is/a/named/pipe/fake/log/file >> /this/is/the/real/log/file
done
```

Yes, I know.  Cue up the award for ["Useless use of cat"](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Or, you can try this C code that does nothing but read from something (could be a regular file or a FIFO), and dumps anything read to a new file, and reopens the file upon receipt of SIGHUP:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
// start with invalid descript so close() doesn't break things
int logFileFD = -1;
const char *logFileName = NULL;
void openLogFile( int sig )
{
    close( logFileFD );
    logFileFD = open( logFileName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0644 );
}
void installSigHandler( void )
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sigemptyset( &sa.sa_mask );
    // do NOT restart system calls
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sa.sa_handler = openLogFile;
    sigaction( SIGHUP, &sa, NULL );
}
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    logFileName = argv[ 2 ];
    openLogFile( SIGHUP );
    installSigHandler();
    int fifoFD = open( argv[ 1 ], O_RDONLY );
    for ( ;; )
    {
        char buffer[ 8 * 1024 ];
        ssize_t bytes = read( fifoFD, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
        if ( bytes > 0L ) write( logFileFD, buffer, bytes );
    }
}
```

I really compressed that code and left off just about all error checking to get rid of any scroll bar.

Comment: I was going precisely in this direction! Though working with Python actually, but yes, this really seems like the most sensible way to go for me at the moment. Thanks !